# Why is my shower faucet turning itself off?

Tags: plumbing, repair, shower, faucet

My shower has a wall mount single lever faucet similar to this: http://www.cn-faucet.com/Wall-Mount-Single-Lever-Faucets-141.html

Over time, it has become more sensitive and now, in most angles, gravity pulls and turns it off, unless water flow is very high. If I turn it to get very hot or very cold water, it becomes less affected, and at only hot or only cold, (when it's almost horizontal), it can stay on with a very slight water flow.

The lever has a screw that holds it to the faucet, and I haven't found anything else to touch.

I use it now without the lever, and it's quite steady (hard to use with the hands, indeed; I usually put the lever to turn it on or change water temp, and then put the lever aside).

What could be the problem, and how could I fix it?

**Update:**

The faucet itself:

[image: valve]

The insides of the lever: 
[image: lever]

You can see the screw at the bottom of the lever; this screw bites the black plastic piece of the faucet to keep it in place; I don't think this is related to my problem, though. 
In the center of said black plastic piece there's a screwhole, but there's no screw in it.

If a more detailed picture of some part is needed just ask for it.

Comment: the screw supposed to fasten the lever. can you send a couple of pictures?

Comment: @Asaf Chertkoff: Here you have.

Comment: The problem is going to be inside of the valve assembly itself, not with the lever attachment, so you'll have to do some more disassembly to find the culprit.

Comment: @B Mitch: Thanks, I'll try to dissassemble it and update the question as needed :-)

Comment: @B Mitch: I seem unable to disassemble anything else. Any suggestion?

Comment: Who is the manufacturer of the faucet?

Comment: @Karl Katzke, the manufacturer is Roca.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like your diverter valve (the round piece w/ the green on it in your pictures) is failing.  It may be as simple a fix as pulling the valve and replacing the gaskets (O rings, probably) and reinserting the valve, or alternatively just replacing the diverter valve entirely.

Unscrew the chrome cap surrounding the diverter valve and the valve itself should pull right out. Take that to a plumbing supply shop/lowes/home depot/someone who carries your brand of faucet.

Comment: The op is talking about the lever moving, not the water turning off. Although what you describe may very well fix the problem anyway.

Comment: @The Evil Greebo: I removed the chrome ring but it seems mostly ornamental. I can't find anything else to remove. There's another chrome piece surrounding the diverter valve (the cap you were refering to?) and this yellowish metal (bronze?) piece but none of them will move and there are no visible screws. Any idea to continue my disassembling task?

Comment: Can you post an updated pic please?